# Open a new html in new tab with angular material with two controllers

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am looking for angular material service which supports communication between two windows with two controllers for each window. I open a new window from my angular form using

```
$window.open("MyNewWindow.")
```

, I want the selection from this window updated to my parent window. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the browser's [sessionStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to store data in the new window then read the same session data in the parent window.  Assuming both windows are in the same domain, you can achieve this easily.

For example, In your new window you can add some values to the `sessionStorage` object, like this:

```
sessionStorage.pageTitle = "my page title"
```

Now you can read the session value from the parent window using: `sessionStorage.pageTitle`